# How to use SetWindowsHookEx function with java?

Tags: java, winapi, java-native-interface, hook, keylogger

I want to log the keys in a table that i have designed in java. To get the keys user is pressing *(on windows)* i am advised to use the function [`SetWindowsHookEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). But i don't know how to use this function. Basically i want `SetWindowsHookEx` to call my java function with the key strokes it has received.Then i will log those keys into the table for the user to see it later. I don't understand the arguments of the mentioned function. Basically how do i use this function to implement the task.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question more than once: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10684594/writing-a-key-listener-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [jnativehook](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook). It's a library for using system-wide keyboard / mouse hooks from Java.

Comment: but i wanted to use `SetWindowsHookEx` and see how can i use it with java

Comment: i have been using it and has been very useful. Thanks:) I had forgotten to accept the answer